# Is it possible to 'pre-compile' a workflow without running it?

Tags: workflow

It takes a long time to start a workflow for the first time. Is it possible to avoid this initial delay without running it?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, but would you consider an alternative?  How about if the first step was a test condition that could bypass all of the other logic.  That should allow you to load it without "running" it.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. I think there is not way for this.